# remove 1 colum from a datagrid using item source

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a datagrid which has an item source of observablecollection and I want to 1 column to be saved int the observablecollection and not show it to the user in the data grid.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the `Column` in the code behind like this:

```
YourDataGrid.Columns[IndexOftheColumn].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Alternatively if you want this to be xaml-only, you should set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` and define custom columns in your `Xaml`.